# Reuse the same FXML declaration for menu bar and context menu

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have declared a menu bar in FXML with a bunch menu items (containing graphics, onClick method links etc...).

Now I'm creating a context menu for a table, and I'd like to put in there all the menu items for the "Edit" menu of the menu bar.

Is there a DRY way of doing so in FXML?

I don't like the idea of copying all the FXML declarations of the menu items, and having to maintain both sets of items.
I know I could reuse the items if I declared them in Java code, but I'd like to keep all my layout in FXML.

Here is the FXML for the edit menu, that I don't want to duplicate:

```
<Menu text="_Edit">
    <MenuItem onAction="#copyRaw" text="Copy _raw log">
        <accelerator>
            <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="C" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
        </accelerator>
        <graphic>
            <Glyph fontFamily="FontAwesome" icon="copy" />
        </graphic>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem onAction="#copyPretty" text="Copy with _columns">
        <accelerator>
            <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="C" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="DOWN" shortcut="UP" />
        </accelerator>
        <graphic>
            <Glyph fontFamily="FontAwesome" icon="copy" />
        </graphic>
    </MenuItem>
    <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
    <MenuItem onAction="#selectAll" text="Select _All">
        <accelerator>
            <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="A" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
        </accelerator>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#unselectAll" text="Unselect All" />
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that my idea is best but u should to do it like this:
  You can create a package in resources with most used elements as Buttons,Tables,Labels etc. for each assign an **fx:id** and include that in another fxmls.
Example:

**PACKAGE**: resource/package/name/utils/Label.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<Label xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
   fx:id="label" 
   style="-fx-background-color: red;
          -fx-font: bold;
          -fx-font-size: 30px;"
   text="Hello world">
<padding>
    <Insets top="5" left="5" right="5" bottom="5"/>
</padding>
</Label>
<!--Add all your nodes there-->
```

**PACKAGE**: resource/package/name/Main.fxml

```
<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="TOP_CENTER" hgap="10" vgap="10">
<fx:include source="Label.fxml"/> <!--There will be displayed all elements from Label.fxml-->
</GridPane>
```

In your case you just need to set **fx:id** for your Menu item and import in another fxml.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to just reuse a custom component here, I'm trying to re-use a whole structure bound to the controller's methods, so it's slightly more complicated than this example.